# Dagger2: Inject RxJava2 Function

Tags: android

I've been following [Hannes Dorfman's MVI tutorial](http://hannesdorfmann.com/android/model-view-intent) and he mentions injecting a function via Dagger to get the code to look similar to the below:

Injected function:

```
@Provides @Singleton
fun providesModelFunc(
    searchEngine: SearchEngine): Function1<Observable<String>, Observable<SearchModel>> =
    { stringObservable ->
        stringObservable.startWith("").flatMap { queryString -> searchEngine.search(queryString) }
    }
```

Function (`modelFunc`) used in class:

```
subscription =
    modelFunc(  // model()
            view.searchIntent()  // intent()
        )
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe( // view()
            view.showData(),
            view.showError()
        )
```

I've been trying to implement a similar thing but not in Kotlin and so far have the function building in the `Module` fine:

```
@Provides
@Singleton
Function<Observable<SearchViewQueryTextEvent>, Observable<Object>> providesSearchFunction(DiscogsInteractor discogsInteractor)
{
    return searchViewQueryTextEventObservable -> searchViewQueryTextEventObservable.flatMap(queryString ->
    {
        if (queryString.toString().equals(""))
            return Observable.just("");
        else
            return discogsInteractor.searchDiscogs(queryString.toString());
    });
}
```

However, using the function in my `Presenter` is causing some trouble. It injects fine:

```
private Function<Observable<SearchViewQueryTextEvent>, Observable<Object>> searchModelFunc;

@Inject
public SearchPresenter(SearchContract.View mView, DiscogsInteractor discogsInteractor, Function<Observable<SearchViewQueryTextEvent>, Observable<Object>> searchModelFunc)
{
    this.mView = mView;
    mInteractor = discogsInteractor;
    this.searchModelFunc = searchModelFunc;
}
```

But as the Kotlin syntax is a little different, I'm struggling to apply it to my intent. I can't use

`searchModelFunc(mView.searchIntent())`

as that's not Android syntax. So I've settled for

`mView.searchIntent().map(searchModelFunc);`

The problem here is that my Function isn't being picked up in the right format:
 [image]

Before I delve into learning Kotlin, what's the correct syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the injection to

```
@Provides
@Singleton
Function<SearchViewQueryTextEvent, ObservableSource<?>> providesSearchFunction(DiscogsInteractor discogsInteractor)
{
    return searchViewQueryTextEvent -> discogsInteractor.searchDiscogs(searchViewQueryTextEvent.queryText().toString());
}
```

And then it could be used like:

```
mView.searchIntent()
                .flatMap(searchModelFunc)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think plainly injecting the function is not the way to go. Consider injecting a funtion accessor object:

```
interface ModelFunctions {
    Function<Observable<SearchViewQueryTextEvent>, Observable<Object>> search();
}
```

This  way you will be able to provide further functions to the presenter if the need arises. Besides, it will make the code more readable.

```
interface ModelFunctions {
    Function<Observable<SearchViewQueryTextEvent>, Observable<Object>> search();

    Function<Observable<SearchViewQueryTextEvent>, Observable<Object>> anotherSearch();
}
```